# Drawing a 3 phase transformer with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a "easy" way draw something like the following in TikZ? I only have the frame but those swirly things are hard to draw:

[image]

```
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) --(0,5) -- (7,5) -- (7,0) -- (0,0) ;
\draw (1,1) -- (1,4) -- (3,4) -- (3,1) -- (1,1) ;
\draw (4,1) -- (4,4) -- (6,4) -- (6,1) -- (4,1) ;
\draw[very thick] (8,4.8) -- (8,2.8);
\draw[very thick] (8,2.2) -- (8,.2);
\draw[very thick] (9,4.8) -- (9,2.8);
\draw[very thick] (9,2.2) -- (9,.2);
\draw[very thick] (10,4.8) -- (10,2.8);
\draw[very thick] (10,2.2) -- (10,.2);
\draw[thick] (-0.3,3.5) -- (1,3.5);
\draw[thick] (1,3.5) to [out=180,in=45] (1.2,3.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You may want to read about the "Circuit Libraries" in the pgf manual.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a PSTricks solution is an option, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\let\Name\MakeUppercase

%%% values needed (automatically calculated)
\usepackage{xfp}

% picture frame
\newcommand*\DiagramHorizontalStart{
  \fpeval{-\WindingRadius-5080/7227}% (5080/7227)mm = 2pt = \psdot diameter (if I am not mistaken)
}
\newcommand*\DiagramHorizontalEnd{
  \fpeval{3*\CoreThickness+2*\CoreholeHorizontal+\WindingRadius
          +\ElectroamgnetComponentDistance+3*\ComponentThickness
          +2*\ComponentsHorizontalDistance+0.1}
}
\newcommand*\DiagramVerticalEnd{
  \fpeval{2*\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical}
}
% intermediate functions
\newcommand*\WirePosition[1]{%
  \fpeval{(#1)*\WindingRadius}
}
\newcommand*\WindingsPositionX[1]{%
  \fpeval{(#1-1)*(\CoreThickness+\CoreholeHorizontal)}
}
\newcommand*\LabelPositionX[1]{%
  \fpeval{\CoreThickness/2+\WindingsPositionX{#1}}
}
\newcommand*\LabelPositionY{%
  \fpeval{(\CoreholeVertical+\WirePosition{4*\NumberOfWindingsBottom+2}
           -\WirePosition{4*\NumberOfWindingsTop+2})/2+\CoreThickness}
}
\newcommand*\ComponentStart{%
  \fpeval{3*\CoreThickness+2*\CoreholeHorizontal+\WindingRadius
          +\ElectroamgnetComponentDistance}
}
\newcommand*\ComponentHeight{%
  \fpeval{\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical/2-2*\ComponentEndHeight
          -\ComponentsVerticalDistance/2}
}
\newcommand*\ComponentNumber[1]{%
  \fpeval{(#1-1)*(\ComponentsHorizontalDistance+\ComponentThickness)}
}
\newcommand*\ComponentNoteX[1]{%
  \fpeval{\ComponentStart+\ComponentNumber{#1}}
}
% core
\newcommand*\Core{
  % `outer frame'
  \psframe(0,0)%
          (\fpeval{3*\CoreThickness+2*\CoreholeHorizontal},
           \fpeval{2*\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical})
  % first hole
  \psframe(\CoreThickness,\CoreThickness)%
          (\fpeval{\CoreThickness+\CoreholeHorizontal},
           \fpeval{\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical})
  % second hole
  \psframe(\fpeval{2*\CoreThickness+\CoreholeHorizontal},\CoreThickness)%
          (\fpeval{2*(\CoreThickness+\CoreholeHorizontal)},
           \fpeval{\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical})%
}
% single winding
\newcommand*\Loop[1]{%
  \psarc(0,\WirePosition{4*#1-1}){\WindingRadius}{90}{270}
  \psline(0,\WirePosition{4*#1-2})(\CoreThickness,\WirePosition{4*#1-2})
  \psarc(\CoreThickness,\WirePosition{4*#1-3}){\WindingRadius}{270}{90}%
}
% collection of windings
\newcommand*\WireFull[1]{%
  \psline{*-}(-\WireEndLength,\WirePosition{4*#1+2})%
             (\CoreThickness,\WirePosition{4*#1+2})
  \psarc(\CoreThickness,\WirePosition{4*#1+1}){\WindingRadius}{270}{90}
  \multido{\iA = 1+1}{#1}{\Loop{\iA}}
  \psline{-*}(0,0)(-\WireEndLength,0)%
}
% label
\newcommand*\Label[2]{%
\def\displacement{0.2}
\def\LabelSeparation{1pt}
  \uput{\LabelSeparation}[90]%
    (\LabelPositionX{#1},\fpeval{\LabelPositionY+\displacement})%
    {$\Psi_{\scriptscriptstyle \Name{#2}}$}
  \uput{\LabelSeparation}[270]%
    (\LabelPositionX{#1},\LabelPositionY)%
    {\psline{->}(0,\fpeval{-1+\displacement})(0,\displacement)}%
}
% windings and label combined
\newcommand*\Column[2]{%
  % top windings
  \rput(\WindingsPositionX{#1},
        \fpeval{(\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical)
                -(\WirePosition{4*\NumberOfWindingsTop+2}
                  +\WindingsCoreCornerDistance)})%
       {\WireFull{\NumberOfWindingsTop}}
  % label
  \Label{#1}{#2}
  % bottom windings
  \rput(\WindingsPositionX{#1},
        \fpeval{\CoreThickness+\WindingsCoreCornerDistance})%
       {\WireFull{\NumberOfWindingsBottom}}%
}
% black component
\newcommand*\BlackComponent[3]{%
  % nodes
  \pnodes%
    (\ComponentNoteX{#1},
     0){P1}%
    (\ComponentNoteX{#1},
     \ComponentEndHeight){P2}%
    (\fpeval{\ComponentStart-\ComponentThickness/2+\ComponentNumber{#1}},
      \ComponentEndHeight){P3}%
    (\fpeval{\ComponentStart+\ComponentThickness/2+\ComponentNumber{#1}},
     \fpeval{\ComponentEndHeight+\ComponentHeight}){P4}%
    (\ComponentNoteX{#1},
     \fpeval{\ComponentEndHeight+\ComponentHeight}){P5}%
    (\ComponentNoteX{#1},
     \fpeval{2*\ComponentEndHeight+\ComponentHeight}){P6}
  % bottom wire
  \psline{*-}(P1)(P2)
  % component
  \psframe[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = black
  ](P3)(P4)
  % top wire
  \psline{-*}(P5)(P6)
  % labels
  \uput[20](P1){$#2$}
  \uput[340](P6){$#3$}%
}
% black component, gathered
\newcommand*\Component[3]{%
  \rput(0,\fpeval{1016/7227}){\BlackComponent{#1}{#2}{#3}}
  \rput(0,\fpeval{\CoreThickness+\CoreholeVertical/2
                  +\ComponentsVerticalDistance/2-1016/7227})%
       {\BlackComponent{#1}{\Name{#2}}{\Name{#3}}}%
}


%%% parameters %%%
% core placement
\newcommand*\CoreThickness{2}
\newcommand*\CoreholeHorizontal{5}
\newcommand*\CoreholeVertical{8}
% wire placement
\newcommand*\WindingsCoreCornerDistance{0.5}
\newcommand*\WireEndLength{0.7}
\newcommand*\WindingRadius{0.15}
% number of windings
\newcommand*\NumberOfWindingsTop{2}
\newcommand*\NumberOfWindingsBottom{3}
% electromagnet--components distance
\newcommand*\ElectroamgnetComponentDistance{4}
% black components
\newcommand*\ComponentEndHeight{0.8}
\newcommand*\ComponentThickness{1}
\newcommand*\ComponentsHorizontalDistance{3}
\newcommand*\ComponentsVerticalDistance{2}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit = 0.5}
\begin{pspicture}%
  (\DiagramHorizontalStart,0)%
  (\DiagramHorizontalEnd,\DiagramVerticalEnd)
 %%% electromagnet
  % core
  \Core
  % wires and labels
  \Column{1}{a}
  \Column{2}{b}
  \Column{3}{c}
 %%% components
  \Component{1}{a}{x}
  \Component{2}{b}{y}
  \Component{3}{c}{z}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that the drawing is 'automated'; you choose the values of all the parameters yourself and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 20):

Here you have a starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,5);
\draw (1,1) rectangle (3,4);
\draw (4,1) rectangle (6,4);

\foreach \i in {0,3,6}{
\begin{scope}[xshift=\i{}cm]
\path[fill] (-0.3,3.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[thick] (-0.3,3.5) -- (1,3.5) arc [start angle=0, delta angle =-180, radius=.5mm, rotate=90];
\draw[thick] (0,3.4) arc [start angle=0, delta angle =180, radius=.5mm, rotate=90] -- (1,3.3) arc [start angle=0, delta angle =-180, radius=.5mm, rotate=90];
\draw[thick] (0,3.2) arc [start angle=0, delta angle =180, radius=.5mm, rotate=90] -- (1.3,3.1);
\path[fill] (1.3,3.1) circle (2pt);
\end{scope}}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Just for fun I've thought it was a good example for practising with `pics` and `quotes`. You need [TiKZ 3.0.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf) which [is going to CTAN](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/discussion/477362/thread/340b50b1/?limit=25#99f5)

The new code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    terminal_a/.pic = {%
        \coordinate (-in) at (-3mm,0);
        \coordinate (-out) at (-3mm,-4.5mm);

        \path[fill] (-in) circle (2pt);
        \draw[thick] (-in)--(0,0)--++(0:1cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-180, radius=.75mm]; 
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.5mm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=180, radius=.75mm]--++(0:1cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-180, radius=.75mm]; 
        \fill (-out) circle (2pt);
        \draw[thick] (-out) -- ++(0:3mm);
        },
    terminal_b/.pic = {%
        \coordinate (-in) at (-3mm,0);
        \coordinate (-out) at (-3mm,-7.5mm);

        \path[fill] (-in) circle (2pt);
        \draw[thick] (-in)--(0,0)--++(0:1cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-180, radius=.75mm]; 
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.5mm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=180, radius=.75mm]--++(0:1cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-180, radius=.75mm]; 
        \draw[thick] (0,-4.5mm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=180, radius=.75mm]--++(0:1cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-180, radius=.75mm]; 
        \fill (-out) circle (2pt);
        \draw[thick] (-out) -- ++(0:3mm);
        },
    field/.pic = {
        \draw[thick,-Stealth] (0,0) -- (90:7mm) node[above] {\tikzpictext};
        }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,5);
\draw (1,1) rectangle (3,4);
\draw (4,1) rectangle (6,4);

\foreach \i/\j in {0/A,3/B,6/C}{
    \pic (upper-\j) at (\i,3.8) {terminal_a};
    \pic (lower-\j) at (\i,2) {terminal_b};
    \pic["$\Psi_\j$"] at ([xshift=5mm]\i,2.2) {field};
    }

\node[left] at (upper-A-in) {A};
\draw[red] (upper-A-out) to [bend right] (lower-A-in);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the example of how to draw the coils, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following library for my three-phase transformers.  (A lot more can be automated.)

[image]

It uses the parts in the section that is commented.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    { % core HV - LV
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {X} %debug
          [thick](a) ++(0.95,3.3) -- +(6.1,0);
    \draw [thick](a) ++(0.95,2.3) -- +(6.1,0);
    \draw [thick](a) ++(0.95,1.3) -- +(6.1,0);
    }
    { % LV star
    \coordinate (a) at (4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {x} %debug
    ++(0,0) node [anchor=north] {$n_2$}
    to [short, *-] 
    ++(-3.5,0) to [short,-] 
    ++(0,3)   to [short,-] 
    ++(+0.5,0)  
    ++(-0.5,-1) to [short,*-] 
    ++(+0.5,0)  
    ++(-0.5,-1) to [short,*-] 
    ++(+0.5,0);
    }
    { % HV delta1
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {X} %debug
    ++(0,3)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,-1) 
    (a)++(0,2)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,-1)
    (a)++(3,3)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0.5,0)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0,-2.5)
    to [short,-]
    ++(-3.25,0)
    to [short,-*]
    ++(0,0.5);
    }
    { % HV conection
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {X}%debug
    ++(-1,0) node [anchor=east] {$N$} 
    to[short, o-] 
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$C$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$B$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$A$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0);
    }
    { % LV conection
    \coordinate (a) at (4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {x}%debug
    ++(0,0)
    to[short, -o] 
    ++(1,0) node [anchor=west] {$n$} 
    ++(-1,1) 
    to[short, -o]
    ++(1,0)node [anchor=west] {$c$} 
    ++(-1,1) 
    to[short, -o]
    ++(1,0) node [anchor=west] {$b$} 
    ++(-1,1) 
    to[short, -o]
    ++(1,0)node [anchor=west] {$a$};
    }
    { % HV Winding
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {X}%debug
    ++(0,1) node [anchor=north] {$C_2$} 
    to [L,*-*, i>^=$i_{CB}$] 
      +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$C_1$};
    \draw
    (a)++(0,2) node [anchor=north] {$B_2$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
      +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$B_1$};
    \draw
    (a)++(0,3) node [anchor=north] {$A_2$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
      +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$A_1$};
    }
    { % LV Winding
    \coordinate (a) at (4,-5);
    \draw (a)
    %node {x} %debug
    ++(-3,1) node [anchor=north] {$c_1$} 
    to [L,*-*, i=$i_{c_{12}}$, v_=$u_{c_{12}}$] 
    +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$c_2$};
    \draw
    (a)++(-3,2) node [anchor=north] {$b_1$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
    +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$b_2$};
    \draw
    (a)++(-3,3) node [anchor=north] {$a_1$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
    +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$a_2$};
    }
\end{circuitikz}


\begin{comment}
Transformer parts.
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node {(0,0)}; 
    { % HV conection
    \coordinate (a) at (-5,5);
    \draw (a)
    node {X}%debug
    ++(-1,0) node [anchor=east] {$N$} 
    to[short, o-] 
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$C$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$B$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0)
    ++(-1,1) node [anchor=east] {$A$} 
    to[short, o-]
    ++(1,0);
    }
    { % LV conection
    \coordinate (a) at (5,5);
    \draw (a)
    node {x}%debug
    ++(0,0)
    to[short, -o] 
    ++(1,0) node [anchor=west] {$n$} 
    ++(-1,1) 
    to[short, -o]
    ++(1,0)node [anchor=west] {$c$} 
    ++(-1,1) 
    to[short, -o]
    ++(1,0) node [anchor=west] {$b$} 
    ++(-1,1) 
    to[short, -o]
    ++(1,0)node [anchor=west] {$a$};
    }
    { % HV Winding
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,1);
    \draw (a)
    node {X}%debug
%   ++(0,1) node [anchor=north] {$C_2$} % option 1
    ++(0,1) node [anchor=south] {$C_2$} % option 2 

    to [L,*-*] 
      +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$C_1$};
    \draw
    (a)++(0,2) node [anchor=north] {$B_2$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
      +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$B_1$};
    \draw
    (a)++(0,3) node [anchor=north] {$A_2$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
      +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$A_1$};
    }
    { % LV Winding
    \coordinate (a) at (4,1);
    \draw (a)
    node {x} %debug
    ++(-3,1) node [anchor=north] {$c_1$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
%   +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$c_2$}; % option 1
    +(3,0) node [anchor=south] {$c_2$}; % option 2
    \draw
    (a)++(-3,2) node [anchor=north] {$b_1$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
    +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$b_2$};
    \draw
    (a)++(-3,3) node [anchor=north] {$a_1$} 
    to [L,*-*] 
    +(3,0) node [anchor=north] {$a_2$};
    }
    { % HV star
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,5);
    \draw (a)
    node {X} %debug
    ++(0,0) node [anchor=north] {$N_2$}
    to [short, *-] 
    ++(3.5,0) to [short,-] 
    ++(0,3)   to [short,-] 
    ++(-0.5,0)  
    ++(+0.5,-1) to [short,*-] 
    ++(-0.5,0)  
    ++(+0.5,-1) to [short,*-] 
    ++(-0.5,0);
    }
    { % LV star
    \coordinate (a) at (4,5);
    \draw (a)
    node {x} %debug
    ++(0,0) node [anchor=north] {$n_2$}
    to [short, *-] 
    ++(-3.5,0) to [short,-] 
    ++(0,3)   to [short,-] 
    ++(+0.5,0)  
    ++(-0.5,-1) to [short,*-] 
    ++(+0.5,0)  
    ++(-0.5,-1) to [short,*-] 
    ++(+0.5,0);
    }
    { % HV delta1
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,13);
    \draw (a)
    node {X} %debug
    ++(0,3)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,-1) 
    (a)++(0,2)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,-1)
    (a)++(3,3)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0.5,0)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0,-2.5)
    to [short,-]
%   ++(-3.25,0) % option 1
    ++(-3.5,0) % option 2
    to [short,-*]
    ++(0,0.5);
    ++(0,0.5)node;
    }
    { % HV delta11
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,9);
    \draw (a)
    node {X} %debug
    ++(0,1)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,1) 
    (a)++(0,2)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,1)
    (a)++(3,1)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0.5,0)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0,2.5)
    to [short,-]
%   ++(-3.25,0) % option 1
    ++(-3.5,0) % option 2
    to [short,-*]
    ++(0,-0.5);
    }
 { % LV delta11
    \coordinate (a) at (4,9);
    \draw (a)
    node {x} %debug
    ++(-3,1)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,1) 
    (a)++(-3,2)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,1)
    % link
    (a)++(-3,3)
    to [short,-]
    ++(-0.5,0)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0,-2.5)
    to [short,-]
%   ++(3.25,0) % option 1
    ++(3.5,0) % option 2
    to [short,-*]
    ++(0,0.5);
    }
    { % LV delta1
    \coordinate (a) at (4,13);
    \draw (a)
    node {x} %debug
    ++(-3,3)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,-1) 
    (a)++(-3,2)
    to [short,-] 
    ++(3,-1)
    %link
    (a)++(-3,1)
    to [short,-]
    ++(-0.5,0)
    to [short,-]
    ++(0,2.5)
    to [short,-]
%   ++(3.25,0) % option 1
    ++(3.5,0) % option 2
    to [short,-*]
    ++(0,-0.5);
    }
    { % core HV - LV
    \coordinate (a) at (-4,17);
    \draw (a)
    node {X} %debug
          [thick](a) ++(0.95,3.3) -- +(6.1,0);
    \draw [thick](a) ++(0.95,2.3) -- +(6.1,0);
    \draw [thick](a) ++(0.95,1.3) -- +(6.1,0);
    }
\end{circuitikz}
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

[circuitikz](/questions/tagged/circuitikz) [three-phase](/questions/tagged/three-phase)