# pgf tikz: DC Motor

Tags: tikz-pgf

which tikz-package would you recommend to do something like this: 
[image: a busy cat]

I could imagine how to do the pole shoes and the magnet but i have no idea how to do the coils.

Greetings

Micele

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX ! Please show us how you do the pole shoes and the magnet, then ! Someone would be more likely to help if you do. (please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/116936))

Comment: See if [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32313/106162) helps.

Comment: A four pole permanent magnet?  I fail to see any advantage (as opposed to a two pole magnet in a three phase coil system).  But that is off topic...

Comment: Don't torment yourself reading 1000 pages of manual for a simple picture, make it hard-coded; Either by `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0)` and so on or by defining nodes on important points and connecting them. The latter allows for some flexibility because you can change the coordinates of the nodes but the connections stay.

Comment: Another transformer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154265/1952

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate, as the real problem of drawing the coils has been asked and solved before.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to do it. I'm sorry for the late response but i lost access to my facebook accout.