# draw Transformer circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, draw, tikz-graphdrawing, engineering

I need a suggestion or help me draw this figure in circuitikz or tikz. thank u:)

[image]

Comment: You can combine a tikz drawing of a transformer with circuitikz components.  I would suggest creating a pic of one wrap of the coil.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70090/3d-helix-torus-with-hidden-lines

Comment: @JohnKormylo I understand what u say  but that drawing is in 3d and I don't want it to be so difficult

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154265/38080 --- you have most of it there.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started.  Note I used `\coilwidth` in the design to make changes easier.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\coilwidth}{0.25}
\tikzset{coil/.pic={\draw plot ({0.61*\coilwidth*sin(25*\x)},0.01*\x);}}% domain=-5:5

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (\coilwidth,\coilwidth) rectangle (2-\coilwidth,2-\coilwidth);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{(2-2*\coilwidth-0.1)/4.5}%
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} {\draw (0.5*\coilwidth, 1.22*\coilwidth+\offset*\i) pic{coil};}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]